# background color doesn't always show up

Tags: css, background-color

I have the following css set up for my page.  When the page loads the background color doesn't always take effect.  I have to refresh my page once or twice before the color works.  Anyone know why?  The background-image isn't as tall as the entire page and it's a gradient.  So I'm taking the bottom pixel color of the gradient and using that as the page bg color.

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #001833;
    background-image: url(images/page_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider asking this over at doctype.com. While it's perfectly fine to ask here there may be more people able to help on DocType.

Comment: Which browser? Or does it occur at any browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #001833 url(images/page_bg.jpg) repeat-x top;
}
```

(You don't need to specify 'left' if its repeating.)

Also, if you're using CSS reset (or not), make sure your body uses 100% height:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```